GitHub Copilot documentation generation overwriting large portions of file
I'm trying to do something I thought would be pretty simple. I have a function in Rust:
impl Config {
    pub fn build(mut args: impl Iterator<Item = String>) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        args.next();

        let n = args.next().expect("No ngram size provided");
        let n = n.parse::<usize>().expect("Unable to parse ngram size");

        let bf = args.next().expect("No buffer factor size provided");
        let bf = bf
            .parse::<usize>()
            .expect("Unable to parse buffer factor size");

        let corpus_path = args.next().expect("No corpus path provided");

        Ok(Config { n, bf, corpus_path })
    }
}

I'm trying to use Copilot to generate a documentation comment for it. I've tried highlighting the whole function body and doing cmd + I then typing /doc. I've tried cmd + I then typing in "Generate a documentation comment for the build function".
When I hit enter it overwrites the entire implementation block plus a few functions below it and leaves an incomplete comment halfway through a function down below.
Does anyone know what's going on? I've tried restarting VS Code a few times but it hasn't changed anything. I was able to get it to generate one documentation comment successfully before this for a struct but since then it's just been going haywire.
